# Why the minified script of index.html is shown(exposure) in webpage after build?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, build

Why does the minify script shown on webpage after build react app?

[This is that my problem how to be shown on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRclh.png)

and the script is existing in the body tag.

```
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function (e) { function r(r) { for (var n, a, i = r[0], c = r[1], l = r[2], s = 0, p = []; s < i.length; s++)a = i[s], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, a) && o[a] && p.push(o[a][0]), o[a] = 0; for (n in c) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c, n) && (e[n] = c[n]); for (f && f(r); p.length;)p.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, l || []), t() } function t() { for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) { for (var t = u[r], n = !0, i = 1; i < t.length; i++) { var c = t[i]; 0 !== o[c] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = a(a.s = t[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function a(r) { if (n[r]) return n[r].exports; var t = n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, a), t.l = !0, t.exports } a.e = function (e) { var r = [], t = o[e]; if (0 !== t) if (t) r.push(t[2]); else { var n = new Promise((function (r, n) { t = o[e] = [r, n] })); r.push(t[2] = n); var u, i = document.createElement("script"); i.charset = "utf-8", i.timeout = 120, a.nc && i.setAttribute("nonce", a.nc), i.src = function (e) { return a.p + "static/js/" + ({}[e] || e) + "." + { 3: "c3101b0a" }[e] + ".chunk.js" }(e); var c = new Error; u = function (r) { i.onerror = i.onload = null, clearTimeout(l); var t = o[e]; if (0 !== t) { if (t) { var n = r && ("load" === r.type ? "missing" : r.type), u = r && r.target && r.target.src; c.message = "Loading chunk " + e + " failed.\n(" + n + ": " + u + ")", c.name = "ChunkLoadError", c.type = n, c.request = u, t[1](c) } o[e] = void 0 } }; var l = setTimeout((function () { u({ type: "timeout", target: i }) }), 12e4); i.onerror = i.onload = u, document.head.appendChild(i) } return Promise.all(r) }, a.m = e, a.c = n, a.d = function (e, r, t) { a.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, a.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, a.t = function (e, r) { if (1 & r && (e = a(e)), 8 & r) return e; if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var t = Object.create(null); if (a.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) a.d(t, n, function (r) { return e[r] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, a.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return a.d(r, "a", r), r }, a.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, a.p = "./", a.oe = function (e) { throw console.error(e), e }; var i = this.webpackJsonpklayhub = this.webpackJsonpklayhub || [], c = i.push.bind(i); i.push = r, i = i.slice(); for (var l = 0; l < i.length; l++)r(i[l]); var f = c; t() }([])</script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.5ff813e9.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.e6bef5f8.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
```

For resolving the problem, I moved the script in the haed tag

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
    <link href="./static/css/main.512e8c28.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>!function (e) { function r(r) { for (var n, a, i = r[0], c = r[1], l = r[2], s = 0, p = []; s < i.length; s++)a = i[s], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, a) && o[a] && p.push(o[a][0]), o[a] = 0; for (n in c) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c, n) && (e[n] = c[n]); for (f && f(r); p.length;)p.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, l || []), t() } function t() { for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) { for (var t = u[r], n = !0, i = 1; i < t.length; i++) { var c = t[i]; 0 !== o[c] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = a(a.s = t[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function a(r) { if (n[r]) return n[r].exports; var t = n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, a), t.l = !0, t.exports } a.e = function (e) { var r = [], t = o[e]; if (0 !== t) if (t) r.push(t[2]); else { var n = new Promise((function (r, n) { t = o[e] = [r, n] })); r.push(t[2] = n); var u, i = document.createElement("script"); i.charset = "utf-8", i.timeout = 120, a.nc && i.setAttribute("nonce", a.nc), i.src = function (e) { return a.p + "static/js/" + ({}[e] || e) + "." + { 3: "c3101b0a" }[e] + ".chunk.js" }(e); var c = new Error; u = function (r) { i.onerror = i.onload = null, clearTimeout(l); var t = o[e]; if (0 !== t) { if (t) { var n = r && ("load" === r.type ? "missing" : r.type), u = r && r.target && r.target.src; c.message = "Loading chunk " + e + " failed.\n(" + n + ": " + u + ")", c.name = "ChunkLoadError", c.type = n, c.request = u, t[1](c) } o[e] = void 0 } }; var l = setTimeout((function () { u({ type: "timeout", target: i }) }), 12e4); i.onerror = i.onload = u, document.head.appendChild(i) } return Promise.all(r) }, a.m = e, a.c = n, a.d = function (e, r, t) { a.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, a.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, a.t = function (e, r) { if (1 & r && (e = a(e)), 8 & r) return e; if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var t = Object.create(null); if (a.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) a.d(t, n, function (r) { return e[r] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, a.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return a.d(r, "a", r), r }, a.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, a.p = "./", a.oe = function (e) { throw console.error(e), e }; var i = this.webpackJsonpklayhub = this.webpackJsonpklayhub || [], c = i.push.bind(i); i.push = r, i = i.slice(); for (var l = 0; l < i.length; l++)r(i[l]); var f = c; t() }([])</script>
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./static/js/2.5ff813e9.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.e6bef5f8.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and it was removed from the webpage, but I have to move the script everytime after build...
further more, if remove the script, the webpage will not render...

Why my app made the minify script after build? and what should I do for resolving?

Comment: This is not an issue to resolve. The code is _uglified_ for others not to make sense. Your browser needs to access the code to render, since Javascript is a language that is running on browsers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.